# get index number of specific key value

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList`:

```
 [{doc_count=1439, count={value=689593.0}, key=a}, {doc_count=1439, count={value=405340.0}, key=b}]
```

I am trying to use `indexOf` or `stream` to get the index number of `key=a` but I can't.

Is there any idea about this?

Comment: Do you have a JSON array?  If not, then can you show us exactly what is stored in your array list?

Comment: Iterate using indices and check the elements. If the element at the current index fits your requirements (i.e. has `key=a`) then return that index. If you reach the end of the array without finding a correct element you don't have an index (which might be indicated by returning -1).

Comment: Tell exactly what you're using and provide some of the not working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java stream to get index number, you can use `IntStream.range()`:

```
//Assume your list variable: myList
OptionalInt IntStream.range(0, myList.size())
     .filter(i -> "a".equals(myList.get(i).getKey()))
     .findFirst();
```